# Regular expression pattern questions?

Tags: python

I am having a hard time understanding regular expression pattern. Could someone help me regular expression pattern to match all words ending in s. And start with a and end with a (like ana). 
How do I write ending?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Besides the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html), there are tutorials all over the Internet.

Comment: I did it using `\b([A-Za-z]*(?:ing|s))\b`: https://regex101.com/r/zD9sE8/1 `?: `is the non-capturing group syntax. We only use it so that we can use the alternation symbol `|`. \b is for word boundaries as explained below in syntonym's answer.

Comment: Could you break each part down for me? Which part represent end?

Answer (score 2):

Word boundaries are given by `\b` so the following regex matches words ending with ing or s: `"\b(\w+?(?:ing|s))\b"` where as `\b` is a word boundary, `\w+` is one or more "word character" and `(?:ing|s)` is an uncaptured group of either `ing` or `s`.

As you asked "how to develop a regex":

First: Don't use regex for complex tasks. They are hard to read, write and maintain. For example there is [a regex that validates email addresses](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) - but its computer generated and nothing you should use in practice.

Start simple and add edge cases. At the beginning plan what characters you need to use: You said you need words ending with `s` or `ing`. So you probably need something to represent a word, endings of words and the literal characters `s` and `ing`. What is a word? This might change from case to case, but at least every alphabetical character. Looking up in the [python documentation on regexes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) you can find `\w` which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which fits my impression of a word character. There you can also find `\b` which is a word boundary.

So the "first pseudo code try" is something like `\b\w...\w\b` which matches a word. We still need to "formalize" `...` which we want to have the meaning of "one ore more characters", which directly translates to `\b\w+\b`. We can now match a word! We still need the `s` or `ing`. `|` translates to or, so how is the following: `\b\w+ing|s\b`? If you test this, you'll see that it will match confusing things like `ingest` which should not match our regex. What is happening? As you probably already saw the `|` can't know "which part it should or", so we need to introduce parenthesis: `\b\w+(ing|s)\b`. Congratulations, you have now arrived at a working regex!

Why (and how) does this differ from the example I gave first? First I wrote `\w+?` instead of `\w+`, the `?` turns the `+` into a non-greedy version. If you know what the difference between greedy and non greedy is, skip this paragraph. Consider the following: `AaAAbA` and we want to match the things enclosed with big letter `A`. A naive try: `A\w+A`, so one or more word characters enclosed with `A`. This matches `AaA`, but also `AaAAbA`, `A` is still something that can be matched by `\w`. Without further config the `*+?` quantifier all try to match *as much as possible*. Sometimes, like in the A example, you don't want that, you can then use a `?` after the quantifier to signal you want a non-greedy version, a version that matches *as little as possible*.

But in our case this isn't needed, the words are well seperated by whitespaces, which are not part of `\w`. So in fact you can just let `+` be greedy and everything will be alright. If you use `.` (any character) you often need to be careful not to match to much.

The other difference is using `(?:s|ing)` instead of `(s|ing)`. What does the `?:` do here? It changes a capturing group to a non capturing group. Generally you don't want to get "everything" from the regex. Consider the following regex: `I want to go to \w+`. You are not interested in the whole sentence, but only in the `\w+`, so you can capture it in a group: `I want to go to (\w+)`. This means that you are interested in this specific piece of information and want to retrieve it later. Sometimes (like when using `|`) you need to group expressions together, but are not interested in their content, you can then declare it as non capturing. Otherwise you will get the group (`s` or `ing`) but not the actual word!

So to summarize:
* start small
* add one case after another
* always test with examples

In fact I just tried `re.findall(`\b\w+(?:ing|s)\b`, "fishing words")` and it didn't work. `\w+(?:ing|s)` works. I've no idea why, maybe someone else can explain that. Regex are an arcane thing, only use them for easy and easy to test tasks.

Comment: since i need words that end with ing or s.. dont i need '\>' ??

Comment: @doctorwho11 Why do you think you need "\>"? Are you talking about HTML? Can you give an example text and what words you are trying to extract from that?

Comment: I am looking at different tutorials to learn and saw this http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/. and it said \> is used for end of word

Comment: @doctorwho11 Maybe that cheatsheet is for a different language. Take a look at [the python specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).  It also has some basic examples. Especially the [example on adverbs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) looks similar to your case. So you can't use `\>` because python regex do not understand that syntax, but if it would, you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I'd use \b to match "word boundaries" with \w which matches word components (short cut for [A-Za-z0-9_]). Then you can do an or grouping to match "s" or "ing". Result is:

```
/\b\w+(s|ing)\b/
```

Comment: Thank you so much answering.. but could you explain how you did it. I want to learn this

Comment: I never used the more complex regexps like the one syntonym is using so perhaps I'm behind in that respect. I started with text processing programs like sed and gawk - these gave a grounding in basic regular expressions without getting overwhelmed (eg: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html and go down to section 3). I found Perl/Python enhanced regexps to be quite complex and it's easy to get intimidated. Start easy with "." and "*" and "+" and then you'll find yourself looking for the tricky stuff as you need it.